# Difference between jackson objectMapper to others

Tags: jackson, objectmapper, mapstruct, mapper, modelmapper

I can't find any explanation about difference between jackson's ObjectMapper to other mappers like dozer/mapStruct/modelMapping/etc. All the articles compare dozer/mapStruct/modelMapping but they ignore ObjectMapper. I can't understand what is wrong? Is the same mapper?

Answer (score 29):

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html), [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) and [ModelMapping](http://modelmapper.org/) are `Java Bean to Java Bean` mappers frameworks that recursively copies data from one object to another, property by property, field by field.

From other side, [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.htmla) provides functionality for reading and writing `JSON`, either to and from basic POJOs, or to and from a general-purpose `JSON Tree Model`. `ObjectMapper` has some additional features like converting objects (see [convertValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) method) but it is not a main reason why this class was created.

So, if you want to implement sophisticated mapping between two different models you should use mappers; if you want to serialise model to `JSON` or deserialise model from `JSON` payload you have to use `ObjectMapper` from [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Answer (score 8):

Jackson library- Mainly concerned with converting Objects/ Entities to JSON and back.

ModelMapper/ MapStruct - Concerned with mapping One entity to another like, mapping an Entity to its DTO. This operation can get pretty gnarly owing to the size and complexity of different entities, so we need these libraries to make work easier.