# How to deserialize json and distinguish `null` from the absence of a value

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data

I have `REST` api, and when client call `POST` request with body, backend after deserialize should distinguish `null` from the absence of a value.

Because if value in `JSON` is null, then `value` in DB should become *null*.

If value in `JSON` absence, then `value` in DB should *remain unchanged*.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "sample name",
  "value" : null
}
```

OR

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "sample name"
}
```

For Java after deserialization it is look like : `value = null;`

**Java:**

```
@Entity
@Table("sample")
public class Sample {
    @Id
    @Column
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private Integer value;

    // getters / setters
}
```

**Sample REST request:**

```
@PutMapping
public ResponseEntity<SampleDto> updateSample(@RequestBody SampleDto dto) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.updateSample(dto));
}
```

**Sample service impl:**

```
public SampleDto updateSample(SampleDto dto) {
  Sample sample = sampleRepository.findById(dto.getId);
  sample.setName(dto.getName());
  sample.setValue(dto.getValue());

//In this operation back need understand: value is null or absence
//Because if value in JSON is null, then value in DB should become null
//If value in JSON absence, then value in DB should remain unchanged

  Sample newSample = sampleRepository.save(sample);
  return modelMapper.map(newSample, SampleDto.class);
}
```

Project use `Spring Data`.

Maybe I should use `@JsonDeserialize` annotation or other `Hibernate` annotation

I tried use `@JsonDeserialize`, but it is not solution.

Comment: Since its the abstracted `save` method you are using, I suggest you can perform a null check and if there's any attributed null, you may use another save method with a `native` query

Comment: This has been answered there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346009/how-to-differentiate-null-value-fields-from-absent-fields-in-jackson-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial update is different from full-resource update and we should implement it in a different way. Let's create two request `POJO` classes. One class will be used to create and update resources, second will be used to partially update given resource. To emphasise it we will use different `HTTP` methods.  To distinguish `null` from `absence` we can use `java.util.Optional` class.

- `SampleCompleteRequest` class we use together with `POST` (create) and `PUT` (update) methods.
- `SamplePartialRequest` class we use together with `PATCH` (partially update) method.

To avoid boilerplate code in this example I'm using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) but it is not required.

---

### Model

```java
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SampleCompleteRequest {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

```java
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Optional;

@Data
public class SamplePartialRequest {
    private Optional<@NotBlank String> name;
    private Optional<String> value;
}
```

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SampleResponse {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Sample {
    //@Id - Hibernate annotations are removed
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

### MapStruct

In `MapStruct` we need to define an interface with all methods we need.

```java
import com.example.demo.model.SampleCompleteRequest;
import com.example.demo.model.SamplePartialRequest;
import com.example.demo.model.SampleResponse;
import jakarta.annotation.Nullable;
import org.mapstruct.BeanMapping;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;
import org.mapstruct.ReportingPolicy;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.mapstruct.MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING;
import static org.mapstruct.NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS;
import static org.mapstruct.NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE;

@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, componentModel = SPRING)
public interface SamplesMapper {
    @BeanMapping(nullValueCheckStrategy = ALWAYS, nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = IGNORE)
    Sample patch(SamplePartialRequest input, @MappingTarget Sample target);

    Sample update(SampleCompleteRequest input, @MappingTarget Sample target);

    SampleResponse mapToResponse(Sample input);

    default String optionalToString(@Nullable Optional<String> nullable) {
        return nullable == null ? null : nullable.orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Plugin will generate boilerplate code for us. Below class is autogenerated and we do not need to implement it manually.

```java
@Component
public class SamplesMapperImpl implements SamplesMapper {

    @Override
    public Sample patch(SamplePartialRequest input, Sample target) {
        if ( input == null ) {
            return target;
        }

        if ( input.getName() != null ) {
            target.setName( optionalToString( input.getName() ) );
        }
        if ( input.getValue() != null ) {
            target.setValue( optionalToString( input.getValue() ) );
        }

        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public Sample update(SampleCompleteRequest input, Sample target) {
        if ( input == null ) {
            return target;
        }

        target.setName( input.getName() );
        target.setValue( input.getValue() );

        return target;
    }

    @Override
    public SampleResponse mapToResponse(Sample input) {
        if ( input == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        SampleResponse sampleResponse = new SampleResponse();

        sampleResponse.setId( input.getId() );
        sampleResponse.setName( input.getName() );
        sampleResponse.setValue( input.getValue() );

        return sampleResponse;
    }
}
```

### Resource

A controller class is easy to implement:

```java
import com.example.demo.model.SampleCompleteRequest;
import com.example.demo.model.SamplePartialRequest;
import com.example.demo.model.SampleResponse;
import com.example.service.SamplesMapper;
import com.example.service.SamplesService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.hateoas.CollectionModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/samples")
public class SamplesResource {

    private final SamplesMapper mapper;
    private final SamplesService samplesService;

    @GetMapping
    public CollectionModel<SampleResponse> listAll() {
        List<SampleResponse> entities = samplesService.list().stream().map(mapper::mapToResponse).toList();

        return CollectionModel.of(entities);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public EntityModel<SampleResponse> addSample(@Valid @RequestBody SampleCompleteRequest request) {
        var entity = samplesService.create(request);
        var response = mapper.mapToResponse(entity);

        return EntityModel.of(response);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "{id}")
    public EntityModel<SampleResponse> updateSample(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody SampleCompleteRequest request) {
        var entity = samplesService.update(id, request);
        var response = mapper.mapToResponse(entity);

        return EntityModel.of(response);
    }

    @PatchMapping(path = "{id}")
    public EntityModel<SampleResponse> partiallyUpdateSample(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody SamplePartialRequest request) {
        var entity = samplesService.patch(id, request);
        var response = mapper.mapToResponse(entity);

        return EntityModel.of(response);
    }
}
```

A service class is also straightforward:

```java
import com.example.demo.model.SampleCompleteRequest;
import com.example.demo.model.SamplePartialRequest;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SamplesService {

    private final SamplesMapper mapper;
    private final SamplesRepository repository;

    public List<Sample> list() {
        return repository.listAll();
    }

    public Sample create(SampleCompleteRequest request) {
        var sample = mapper.update(request, new Sample());
        return repository.save(sample);
    }

    public Sample update(Long id, SampleCompleteRequest request) {
        var sample = repository.find(id).orElseThrow();
        mapper.update(request, sample);

        return repository.save(sample);
    }

    public Sample patch(Long id, SamplePartialRequest request) {
        var sample = repository.find(id).orElseThrow();
        mapper.patch(request, sample);

        return repository.save(sample);
    }
}
```

See also:

1. [HTTP PUT vs HTTP PATCH in a REST API](https://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring)
2. [Difference between Jackson objectMapper to others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600368/difference-between-jackson-objectmapper-to-others)
3. [Spring MVC PATCH method: partial updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52135000/51591)